# Lebesgue's points Sobolev functions

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, sobolev-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Given $u\in W^{1,p}_{loc}(U)$, define 
$$u_{x,r}:=\frac{1}{|B(x,r)|}\int_{B(x,r)}u(y)dy.
$$
I proved that 
$$
\frac{d}{dr}u_{x_0,r}\le Cr^{\frac{\varepsilon}{p}-1}
$$
 for $r\in (0,\frac{1}{2}\text{dist}(x_0,\partial U))$ and $\varepsilon>0$ small enough.

I don't know how to conclude that 
$$
\lim_{r\to 0}u_{x_0,r} 
$$
exists and is finite.

I thought to use Poincaré inequality, but I can't succeed.

Comment: I am little confused here. Could you please clearly state the whole problem?

Comment: These passages are from the proof of Federer & Ziemer Thm about the Hausdorff dimension of the Lebesgue's points of Soboleve functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix some $r_0$ so that $B(x_0,r_0)\subset U$.
If you know that $(0,r_0)\ni r\mapsto u_{x_0,r}$ is differentiable and satisfies
$$
\left|\frac{d}{dr}u_{x_0,r}\right|\leq Cr^{\frac{\varepsilon}{p}-1},
$$
you can use the fundamental theorem of calculus to observe that
$$
u_{x_0,r}=u_{x_0,r_0}-\int_r^{r_0}\frac{d}{ds}u_{x_0,s}ds
$$
for all $r\in(0,r_0)$ and the limit as $r\to0$ exists and is finite since the integral is absolutely convergent (by the estimate).